# Problem with a particle System, two strange problems

Tags: animation, particles

I'm makin an animation where I want to show the way
of x-ray radiation through a device. To keep it doable
for me I use multiple sources for "radiation"-particles,
starting at one, flying to the next one, getting destroyed
there, then new ones getting created. I basically created
one radiation particle system and multiplied that for the
other sources so I just had to change the source, the starting
frame and the amount. Now I have encountered two problems:

A) Even though I deactivated any influence on the particles
except for getting killed on certain objects, there is a phase
where the radiation flies through a tube and they get slower
and slower and stop moving as if there was some kind of resistance
or friction. I cannot figure out the reason just why only THIS 
specific particle System has this problem. (note: another particle
System exists, similar to this, particles flying through a tube and
there is no drag)

B) I "kinda" fixed my problem by speeding up the particles of THAT
particular System, then I tweaked the starting frames of the latter
parts so it still looks kinda fluid. Now three particle Systems that
were fully funtional before stopped working properly. Instead of the
average of 2 particles per frame it should send out it only sends out
2 particles in the rendered time (about two thirds of the whole time I
planned this animation to have). What reasons could that be?

I'd be happy if someone would know some ideas how to fix this.

Comment: Share some screenshots and concrete settings, or even better, a simplified blend file that shows the problem. With just an anecdotal description we can't give you a concrete solution.